# Can I export/import classes from more than one entry point?

Tags: typescript

I've not found a clear answer to this, despite a lot of searching. I suspect it might just be impossible by design, but the docs I've seen don't explicitly say anything either way.

I want to create a package with both an `index.js` entry point and an `internal.js` entry point. The idea is that when using the normal "customer facing" API, you use only `index.js` and for internal extensions, you use `internal.js`. This is a valuable "forcing function" to indicate when users are trying to access less stable APIs, or APIs that are more prone to misuse.

In my cases it's utterly infeasible to split these internal APIs into a whole separate project.

I have packaged my project and deployed to NPM repository, and installed it locally, but I cannot see a way to import the internal API now.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonenumbers_js

```
import {
    AbstractPhoneNumberClassifier,
    FormatType,
    PhoneNumber,
    PhoneNumberFormatter,
    PhoneNumberParser,
    SchemaVersion } from "phonenumbers_js";
```

All works, but I don't see a syntax to let me import something from the `internal.js` file, e.g:

```
import { Converter } from "phonenumbers_js/internal";
```

```
src/index.ts:18:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'phonenumbers_js/internal' or its corresponding type declarations.

18 import { Converter } from "phonenumbers_js/internal";
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this kind of good-practice API separation just not possible in TypeScript? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Answered:

It turns out that to import an individual file, you have to retain the package file structure (which does make sense).

So if you think of:

```
import { ... } from "phonenumbers_js";
```

as shorthand for:

```
import { ... } from "phonenumbers_js/dist/index.js";
```

where `dist` is the directory in the package in which code lives, then it's clearer that what I needed was:

```
import { Converter } from "phonenumbers_js/dist/internal.js";
```